# Using CSS3, solid black background that is 95% transparent?

Tags: css

Using CSS3, what RGB-like value should replace VALUE below in order to achieve a solid black background that is 95% transparent?

```
div { background: VALUE }
```

Thanks Folks!!!

Answer (score 4):

RGBa (a for alpha)

```
div { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05)};
```

Comment: `rgba(0, 0, 0, .95)` -> 95% opaque, 5% transparent. no?

Comment: Yea, I think I mixed up the wording and what the OP was looking for. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

RGBa, i think:

```
div {
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an RGBA notation.
R for red, G for Green, B for Blue and the A for aplha (percentage of transparency, as you've asked).

So the best answer is :

```
div {
    background : rgba(0, 0, 0, .95);
}
```

And don't worry, it's supported by all the major browsers (even IE since IE 9) : http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Answer (score 1):

Folks i took a challenge test online and the following is the answers they provided to my question above:

```
div { background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check, I ran a test on my system and @Blingue is definitely correct.
Use div {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05)}